# adding and removing classname with eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set eventlistener to a button

```
<button id="btn">click me</button>

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
test(e.target);
}, false);
```

And each time click is triggered, the other HTML element(`.random ul`) will get a new class of `my class` or remove it(on the second click)

```
function test() {
document.querySelector(".random ul").className = document.querySelector(".random ul").className += ' newclass'
    ? '' //need to remove the newclass
    : ''; //need to add the newclass
}
```

This obviously not working. I also found the following script to properly remove added classname:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className =
   document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' )
//from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript
```

I really don't know how to make it work and would like to ask you to help me with it please.

Comment: In which browsers does this have to work?

Comment: what's wrong with this one ? `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 e.target.classList.toggle('hello')
}, false);`

Comment: All modern browsers, IE9 and above. Most of mobile browsers.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you think this is a duplicate, please mark it accordingly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applaud you for not using jQuery. Some time ago I took the dive myself. This script may solve your problem, even for very old browsers:

```js
function toggleClass (el, className) {
  if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.toggle(className);
  } else {
    if (el.className.match(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+className+'(\\s|$)','g'))) {
      el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('\\s?' + className), '');
    }
    else {
      el.className += ((el.className !== '') ? ' ' : '') + className;
    }
  }
}


document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  toggleClass(document.querySelector('.random ul'), 'newclass');
}, false);
```

```css
.newclass { color: red; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>

<div class="random">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Oh, and for more Vanilla-JS-stuff, get inspired by http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ or my personal experiments at https://github.com/fboes/js-toolshed/blob/master/src/js-toolshed.js

Answer (score 1):

In all modern browsers (IE 10+), you could use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its `toggle` method:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    test(e.target); // not sure why you need e.target?
}, false);

function test() {
    document.querySelector('.random ul').classList.toggle('newclass');
}
```

`toggle` works like jQuery's toggle.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this approach. But unfortunately it doesn't work in IE9.